# passing File pointer in Go

Tags: go

Ok, I've been programming in Go for a few days so I could be considered a newbie, but I cannot figure out how to import the definition of the File struct. I want to pass a *File into a func and I can't seem to get File defined. I'm importing "os" and calling os.Create in my main. How do I import the right item or declare the parameter in my func definition to pass a file pointer?

```
import "os"
func testfunc(fp *File) { ... }
fp := os.Create("myfile")
testfunc(fp)
```

Answer (score 8):

Your testfunc declaration should look like this:

```
func testfunc(fp *os.File) { ... }
```

I was stuck about half an hour on this one.
Anyway, I hope this helps some other people as well.

Answer (score -2):

Give the qualified path to the struc File

```
import "os"
func testfunc(fp *os.File) { ... }
fp := os.Create("myfile")
testfunc(fp)
```

Comment: os.Create returns a *File and an error. Also it is not a "qualified path" but a package name (see http://golang.org/ref/spec#Qualified_identifiers). Nitpick: This has nothing to do with os.File, that's how accessing stuff from packages works.